# Why doesn't setting an invalid enum value cause error handler to be invoked?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Mysql 5.7 , Tables have Innodb storage engine.

```
create table test_tran (id integer, descr varchar(255));

create table test_enum (id int, flag enum('good','not good') not null);
```

A valid record is insert into test_enum table

```
insert into test_enum values(1,'good')
```

I have stored procedure with transaction defined which tries to update an invalid value in the enum column. It also catches the error to rollback the transaction, then resignals the error.

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_tran;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test_tran
(
 
i_case integer
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  
        RESIGNAL;
    END;
    

    START TRANSACTION;
    

    IF i_case=0 THEN
      insert into test_tran values (1, 'abc');
      update test_enum set flag='random'; 
    ELSE
    
      insert into test_tran values (3, 'else_1_abc');
      insert into test_tran values (4, 'else_2_abc');
      END IF; 
    
    COMMIT;
    


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I execute

```
call test_tran(0)
```

and get an error - "Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'flag' at row"

I was expecting the below statement to rollback

```
 insert into test_tran values (1, 'abc');
```

However, I see it getting committed and I see the row inserted in test_tran table. What is causing the issue?

Comment: `flag = 'random'`.  That is not a valid value.

Comment: yes, flag = 'random' is not a valid value and I was expecting the transaction to rollback but I observed the insert prior to the update statement getting commited

Answer (score 0):

The key piece of information is missing from the error message: the SQLSTATE. The full error message should be:

> ERROR: 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'flag' at row 1

(Likely the client being used isn't including the SQLSTATE in the error message; the above is what MySQL Shell produces.)

The documentation for [`DECLARE ... HANDLER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html) states:

> The condition_value for `DECLARE ... HANDLER` indicates the specific condition or class of conditions that activates the handler. It can take the following forms:
>
> ...
>
> - SQLWARNING: Shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin with '01'.
>
> ...
>
> - SQLEXCEPTION: Shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that do not begin with '00', '01', or '02'.

The error generated by setting an invalid enum column is part of the SQLWARNING class, not SQLEXCEPTION, so the error handler is never invoked and the transaction is still active after the procedure exits, which is why the inserted row appears in `test_tran`. Note the transaction could be rolled back manually at that point; also, closing the session will cause an automatic rollback.

To handle the error in `test_tran`, simply change SQLEXCEPTION to SQLWARNING, or (perhaps more appropriate) add conditions to the handler:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_tran (i_case integer)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND, SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  
        RESIGNAL;
    END;
    ...
```

---

Note for other readers: some may be wondering why the `DECLARE ... HANDLER` is needed; why the entire transaction isn't cancelled by the error. The  [InnoDB error handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-error-handling.html) page describes when implicit rollbacks occur. The only time the entire transaction is automatically rolled back is if there's a transaction [deadlock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html), or if a lock times out while waiting and the server was started with [`--innodb-rollback-on-timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_rollback_on_timeout) set. Setting a column to an invalid `enum` value

> [is] mostly detected by the MySQL layer of code (above the InnoDB storage engine level), and they roll back the corresponding SQL statement. Locks are not released in a rollback of a single SQL statement.

In other words, the query that set the invalid enum value is rolled back, but the transaction is not.